# I'm trying to add images to a RecyclerView using RecyclerVIewAdapter and Picasso

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I tried to do that but i had no luck, the images don't show on the screen
I'm pretty new to this so here's my code

My RecyclerViewAdapter:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public Context context;
    public ArrayList<MoviesData> array;
    public LayoutInflater inflater;


    RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<MoviesData> array)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.array = array;
        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }



    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView image;


        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
             image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.oneMovieBlockImageView);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.movie_block,parent,false);

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(rootview);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {


        //holder.image.setImageResource(Picasso.with(context).load(array.get(position).getPoster_path()).into(image));
        MoviesData current = array.get(position);
        Picasso.with(context).load(current.getPoster_path()).into(holder.image);


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

My LinearLayout which has the RecyclerView

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.themovieapp.MainActivityFragment"
    >


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        >


    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

My ImageView

```
<ImageView

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:id="@+id/oneMovieBlockImageView"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"

    >
</ImageView>
```

onCreateView method

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    updateMovies();


    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main,container,false);


    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(),moviesDatas);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));


    return rootView;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Adapter is empty

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 0;
}}
```

Please update to `return array.size();`

Comment: That gave me NullPonterException.
Does it mean that the Arraylist is empty ?

Comment: Well, then you have not initialized the list when you do `new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(),moviesDatas);`

Comment: Sorry, but i don't understand you
What am i supposed to do ?

Comment: How about you initialize the List in the Fragment? `moviesDatas = new ArrayList<MoviesData>()`